# In C#, how can I order a list after its grouped by size of the list?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Lets say I have a collection of car objects

3  blue cars
10 yellow car
5 red cars

```
List<Car> cars = GetList();
var groupBy = cars.GroupBy(r=>r.Color);
```

I now want to sort the groupBy grouped collection in descending order so I first get the yellow cars, then red and then blue when i loop through the list

What is the correct way to sort a grouped list by the size of the collection in that entry of the group by list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = cars.GroupBy(r=>r.Color).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you group a collection, you will get a `IEnumerable<Grouping<TKey, TValue>>` collection which has the `Key` property and `Value` property. The `Key` is the value which you have grouped and the `Value` is the entire object grouped by the `Key`. You also have all extensions for `IEnumerable`.

In your case, you could just call the `OrderByDescending` method passing the `Count()` method from group colelction, for sample:

```
var result = cars.GroupBy(r=>r.Color).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count());
```

Comment: I think @leora is want to `sort a grouped list by the size of the collection`